# How to execute multiple commands within the same input

Tags: linux, sorting

Cyber newbie.
This has me completely stumped. I need to search a file called ‘countries’ for all countries containing the letter ‘y’. Following this, sort the output of this command in reverse order and write the output to a file called ‘output’. 
How do I sort by a particular character?

Thanks

Comment: Could you give an example of the input and the expected output. I may not understand your question. And also you don't know where is the file named countries, and you want to find it first ?

Comment: I know where the file is it just needs sorting. I think the outcome is that I want all countries with the letter y sorted in reverse and then saved as a new file.

Comment: what do you mean by "sorted in reverse"? Reverse alphabetical? Reverse from the original file?

Comment: Are there words in the file that are not countries? Example input/output is needed.

Comment: No they are all countries, i just need to sort the ones with the letter Y in. I can sort the file and save it i just dont know how to sort by the particular character Y? This is what i have done so far;  sort -d -r -o output countries

Answer (score 3):

```
grep y countries | sort -r > output
```

should do it.

The pipe character | sends the output of the command on the left, grep, as input to the right, sort.

The output redirection character > sends the output of the result to a file 
'output'.

Comment: LEGEND!!! sorted, thanks very much I've been trying to figure that for hrs.